# How to get div containing some text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div class="linkL 01 mp3/01.mp3 imgT/03.jpg">lorem1 - part1</div>
<div class="linkL 02 mp3/02.mp3 imgT/03.jpg">lorem2 - part2</div>
<div class="linkL 03 mp3/03.mp3 imgT/03.jpg">lorem3 - part3</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var numera = window.location.hash;
var numera  = numera.replace("#","");
console.log(numera); // `part3`
var author = $(".linkL:contains(numera)").html().split(" - ")[0];
```

I would like to have the result of `lorem3`

But this is what the console says:

```
index.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

Comment: but numera there isnt on any div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that you are concatenating the value is wrong,

```
var author = $(".linkL:contains(" + numera + ")").text().split(" - ")[0];
```

You have to concatenate the variable using `+`, If you don't then that variable name would be considered as a plain string. That value it holds will not be concatenated.

And the class name that you are using `mp3/01.mp3` is invalid. A valid class name should follow [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) rules.

Comment: It'd probably also be better to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`. that way, we're only dealing with the content itself and not its stringified markup.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find lorem3, then you could loop through each of the divs looking for it.

```
  $(".linkL:contains(" + numera + ")").each(function() {
var author = $(this).text().split(" - ")[0];
if (author == "lorem3") {
  $(".result").text($(this).attr('class'));
}});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffld/4e2r5368/1/)